# Conseguir vuelva a preguntarme otro numero si esta fuera del rango, lenguaje python

Tags: python, condiciones, while

No comprendo como conseguir que me vuelva a realizar la funcion cuando doy un numero fuera de rango. El lenguaje que estoy usando para hacer el codigo es python.

**Codigo**

```
def pide_entero():
min=1
max=3
write=int(input())

if min<=write<=max:
    print(write)
      
if write<min or write>max:
    print("vuelve a intentarlo")+pide_entero()        
pide_entero()
```

Comment: ¿ Que lenguaje es ? Parece `python`. Por favor, coloca la etiqueta de lenguaje adecuada y formatea adecuadamente tu código. Pulsa en el enlace de [edtiar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/408523/edit). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que llamar a la función **debajo** del *print()*

```
def pide_entero():
    min=1
    max=3
    write=int(input())

    if min<=write<=max:
        print(write)
  
    if write<min or write>max:
        print("vuelve a intentarlo")
        pide_entero()

pide_entero()
```

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de situaciones normalmente se ataca con un `while True:` dentro del cual se ejecuta la acción (pedir un valor entero) hasta que se cumpla la condición deseada, y en tal caso, se sale con un `break`.

```
def pide_entero():
    min = 1
    max = 3
    while True:
        write = int(input())
        if min <= write <= max:
            break;
        else:
            print("vuelve a intentarlo")
    print(write)

pide_entero()
```

Además, al usar el ciclo `while` evito tener que hacer una llamada recursiva complementamente innecesaria.

Comment: Gracias me salvaste de un suspenso, eternamente agradecido